# Notebook contents replaced with Null

Tags: notebooks

I opened a notebook that I had recently made only to discover that all cells except the first one (an initialization cell) have been removed and all titles/subtitles except the first one have been replaced with Null:
[image: Notebook where almost everything has been replaced/deleted for some reason]

When looking at the contents of the notebook with a text editor it looks like all the cells, except for the first few, contain ExpressionUUID rules and that's about it:

```
Cell[CellGroupData[{

 Cell[, "Chapter",ExpressionUUID->"66a71787-6d65-43a3-9b8f-34451bd45f4a"],

 Cell[, "Text",ExpressionUUID->"e7bade7e-7eb6-4d94-be86-47010d44f9d9"],

 Cell[, "Input",ExpressionUUID->"831f561d-3f2d-45fc-90c8-3d915228040b"],

 Cell[, "Input",ExpressionUUID->"902ce406-b2f0-4389-b2b9-af7876aae1a1"]
}, Open  ]],

...
```

Does anyone know what the cause of such a problem could be? It happened to me twice now, and I don't have a clue what causes this behaviour.

I did notice very odd behaviour with this notebook before: often when moving the cursor with arrow keys, the code font would change to a serif-type font. I couldn't identify the trigger for this behaviour as well so I didn't want to post about it.

Comment: You should contact Tech Support.